# Elementary Number Theory: Divisibility proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $k,m,n \in N\setminus \{0\}$, s.t. $n=k\cdot m$. Show that 
$k$ is odd $\Rightarrow ∀ a,b \in Z: (a^m+b^m) \mid (a^n+b^n)$

In the first part of the task, I have already shown that 
$∀ a,b \in Z: (a^m-b^m) \mid (a^n-b^n)$

Comment: You need to show that for $k, m, n \in \mathbb N\setminus \{0\}$, **if k is not even (hence if k is odd)**, *then* $\forall a, b \in \mathbb Z: (a^m - b^m)\mid (a^n - b^n)$.

Comment: But I've already shown that in the first part for all  $k \in N\setminus \{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

$a^{km} +b^{km} =(a^m +b^m )( a^{(k-1)m} -a^{(k-2)m} b^m +...+a^{m} b^{(k-2)m} +b^{(k-1)m} )$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** if $k$ is odd then $$a^n + b^n = a^{km} + b^{km}
= (a^m)^k - (-b^m)^k
$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that, if $k$ is odd, then $u+v \mid u^k + v^k$. Now let $u = a^m$ and $v = b^m$.